# Bash - Expanding variables for command arguments leads to quoting hell

Tags: bash, rsync, quotes, variable-expansion

So, I'm scripting an `rsync` command. I've been fiddling around for the **entire** day. It's time to ask for help.

My issue appears to be quoting, but it's not obvious to me exactly what's going wrong. This snippet:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo -v
COMMAND=`basename ${0}`

SRC='/etc'
SRC=`realpath ${SRC}` # make relative paths absolute
SRC=${SRC}/ # force rsync to disallow symlinks to the parent path

if [[ ! -d ${SRC} ]];
then
    echo Use ${COMMAND} to backup directories only
    exit 1
fi

BACKUP_DIR='/tmp/backup prep'
TMP_DIR=${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp
DEST=${BACKUP_DIR}/`basename ${SRC}`
LOG_DIR=${TMP_DIR}
LOG_FILE=${LOG_DIR}/${COMMAND}-`date +%Y-%b-%d-%H-%M-%S-%N`.log
for DIR in "${BACKUP_DIR}" "${TMP_DIR}" "${LOG_DIR}"
do
    if [[ ! -d "'${DIR}'" ]];
    then
        echo Creating "'${DIR}'"
        sudo mkdir "${DIR}"
    fi
done

RSYNC_OPTS=""

#--dry-run, -n
RSYNC_OPTS=${RSYNC_OPTS}" --dry-run"
# --recursive, -r          recurse into directories
RSYNC_OPTS=${RSYNC_OPTS}" --recursive"
#--filter=RULE, -f        add a file-filtering RULE
RSYNC_OPTS=${RSYNC_OPTS}" --filter='dir-merge,p- .gitignore'"

# --checksum, -c           skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
RSYNC_OPTS=${RSYNC_OPTS}" --checksum"

echo "rsync ${RSYNC_OPTS} '${SRC}' '${DEST}'" | sudo tee "${LOG_FILE}"
echo --------
echo --------
echo
echo
set -x
sudo rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS} '${SRC}' '${DEST}'"
```

Produces this:

```
Creating '/tmp/backup prep'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/backup prep’: File exists
Creating '/tmp/backup prep/tmp'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/backup prep/tmp’: File exists
Creating '/tmp/backup prep/tmp'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/backup prep/tmp’: File exists
rsync  --dry-run --recursive --filter='dir-merge,p- .gitignore' --checksum '/etc/' '/tmp/backup prep/etc'
--------


+ sudo rsync ' --dry-run --recursive --filter='\''dir-merge,p- .gitignore'\'' --checksum '\''/etc/'\'' '\''/tmp/backup prep/etc'\'''
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/home/aaron/bin/ --dry-run --recursive --filter='dir-merge,p- .gitignore' --checksum '/etc/' '/tmp/backup prep" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]
```

And appears to do nothing.

The thing is, if I sudo the echoed command line, `sudo rsync  --dry-run --recursive --filter='dir-merge,p- .gitignore' --checksum '/etc/' '/tmp/backup prep/etc'`
Everything seems to work as expected.

Shell expansion gets me every bloody time. It'd be nice if there were a command that'd show you what the hell is going on.

Comment: [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) are your friends. Store arguments in an array, not a regular parameter.

Comment: You may want to use shellcheck.net on your code as well.

Comment: Also, `-d "'${DIR}'"` tests if the name constructed from single quotes and the value of `$DIR` is a directory. Drop the single quotes.

Comment: "Shell expansion gets me every bloody time" Funny how folks usually reach for bash when the want a simple, straightforward scripting language, but shell scripting is neither simple nor straightforward.  you could always use a more comfortable language for this -say, python, looking at your question history

Comment: `It'd be nice if there were a command that'd show you what the hell is going on.` You can execute the script with `/bin/bash -x` or put `set -x` at the top of the script to get debug output which will give you a picture of how bash is interpreting the faulty line.

Comment: If you put `set -x` in your terminal before copy and pasting the command you will see some differences between the output of your script and the output on the CLI.

Comment: The string between double quotes in `rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS} '${SRC}' '${DEST}'"` will be expanded as a single word (that is, `rsync` will see it as a single argument). You may want to read [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: It's better to use $(code) instead of \`code\`. These \`\` considered as deprecated and read worst than $(). Specially in this case with a lot of ' and ".

Comment: @Ivan Obsolete, but never actually deprecated. (Deprecation is a stated intent to drop support for something. Backticks aren't recommended, but there are no plans to get rid of them.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my finished script. Many thanks to the commentors on my question. With your hints I was able to make progress.

For what it's worth, the objective was to periodically back up a /etc that is using `etckeeper` and *keep* the .git repo, but ignore stuff in .gitignore

Some observations:

- When building a list of arguments for a command, an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) is totally the way to go.
- When using the array, the shell beautifully quotes values with spaces. Yo can see this by using `set -x` in the script below.
- Using `set -x` is *really* helpful.
- When you're struggling to get something working [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an amazing diagnostic tool.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$(basename "${0}")
SRC="/etc"
BACKUP_DIR="/root/backup prep"
TMP_DIR="${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp"
LOG_DIR="${TMP_DIR}"

if ! sudo -v
then
    echo ${COMMAND} quitting...
    exit 1
fi

SRC=$(realpath "${SRC}") # make relative paths absolute
SRC="${SRC}"/ # force rsync to disallow symlinks to the parent path

# https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086
# Note that $( ) starts a new context, and variables in it have to
# be quoted independently
LOG_FILE="${LOG_DIR}/${COMMAND}-$(date +%Y-%b-%d-%H-%M-%S-%N).log"
for DIR in "${BACKUP_DIR}" "${TMP_DIR}" "${LOG_DIR}"
do
    if sudo test ! -d "${DIR}";
    then
        echo Creating "${DIR}"
        sudo mkdir "${DIR}"
    fi
done

RSYNC_OPTS=()

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Testing----------------
# ------------------------------------
#
#--dry-run, -n
#RSYNC_OPTS+=("--dry-run")

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Verbosity--------------
# ------------------------------------
#
# --verbose, -v            increase verbosity
#RSYNC_OPTS+=("--verbose")
# --progress               show progress during transfer
#RSYNC_OPTS+=("--progress")
# --itemize-changes, -i    output a change-summary for all updates
#RSYNC_OPTS+=("--itemize-changes")
# --stats                  give some file-transfer stats
#RSYNC_OPTS+=("--stats")
# --human-readable, -h     output numbers in a human-readable format
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--human-readable")
# --log-file=FILE          log what we're doing to the specified FILE
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--log-file=${LOG_FILE}")
# --log-file-format=FMT    log updates using the specified FMT


# ------------------------------------
# -------------Permissions------------
# ------------------------------------
#
# --owner, -o              preserve owner (super-user only)
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--owner")
# --group, -g              preserve group
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--group")
# --perms, -p              preserve permissions
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--perms")
# --xattrs, -X             preserve extended attributes
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--xattrs")
# --acls, -A               preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--acls")

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Times------------------
# ------------------------------------
#
# --times, -t              preserve modification times
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--times")
# --crtimes, -N            preserve create times (newness)
# rsync: This rsync does not support --crtimes (-N)
# RSYNC_OPTS+=("--crtimes")
# --atimes, -U             preserve access (use) times
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--atimes")
# --open-noatime           avoid changing the atime on opened files
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--open-noatime")

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Where------------------
# ------------------------------------
#
# --mkpath                 create the destination's path component
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--mkpath")
# --recursive, -r          recurse into directories
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--recursive")
# --links, -l              copy symlinks as symlinks
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--links")
# Rsync can also distinguish "safe" and "unsafe" symbolic links.  An
# example where this might be used is a web site mirror that wishes to
# ensure that the rsync module that is copied does not include symbolic
# links to /etc/passwd in  the public section of the site.  Using
# --copy-unsafe-links will cause any links to be copied as the file they
# point to on the destination.  Using --safe-links will cause unsafe
# links to be omitted altogether. (Note that you  must  specify --links
# for --safe-links to have any effect.)
# --copy-unsafe-links      where the link would point outside of the new tree, copy the file
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--copy-unsafe-links")
# --hard-links, -H         preserve hard links
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--hard-links")
# --one-file-system, -x    don't cross filesystem boundaries
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--one-file-system")

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Exclusions-------------
# ------------------------------------
#
#--filter=RULE, -f        add a file-filtering RULE
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--filter=dir-merge,p- .gitignore")
# --delete-excluded        also delete excluded files from dest dirs
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--delete-excluded")
#--delete-after           receiver deletes after transfer, not during
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--delete-after")
# --force                  force deletion of dirs even if not empty
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--force")
# --update, -u             skip files that are newer on the receiver
#RSYNC_OPTS=${RSYNC_OPTS}" --update")

# ------------------------------------
# -------------Misc-------------------
# ------------------------------------
#
# --protect-args, -s       no space-splitting; wildcard chars only
# This option sends all filenames and most options to the remote rsync
# without allowing the remote shell  to  interpret  them.
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--protect-args")
# --checksum, -c           skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--checksum")
# --temp-dir=DIR, -T       create temporary files in directory DIR
RSYNC_OPTS+=("--temp-dir=${TMP_DIR}")

#echo sudo rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS[@]}" "'${SRC}'" "'${DEST}'"
#echo
#set -x
sudo rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS[@]}" "${SRC}" "${DEST}"
```